# how to limit input locale to en-US

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-edittext

I have an android unit converter app, I am adding more languages to it as it was originally in English only.
I designed my own soft keyboard for use in the app and disabled the default soft keyboard.
the soft keyboard uses buttons and onclick listeners to put text directly onto an edittext.

here is some code for my buttons. amount and amount2 are edittexts

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    myVib.vibrate(25);
                    if(getCurrentFocus()==amount){
                        amount.append("2");
                    }
                    if(getCurrentFocus()==amount2){
                        amount2.append("2");
                    }
                }
            });
            b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    myVib.vibrate(25);
                    if(getCurrentFocus()==amount){
                        amount.append("3");
                    }
                    if(getCurrentFocus()==amount2){
                        amount2.append("3");
                    }
                }
            });
```

all was well till I added some locales like Arabic and Afrikaans, when I use the Arabic locale, pressing the button that inputs a 1 in English inputs the Arabic symbol/number for 1, this causes crashes as it can't be parsed to number for calculation, also in Afrikaans the "." isn't working,

what am asking is if there a way to lock all input to strictly English but still maintaining the other locales for things like resources.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this seems to work.
By pasting this code within the OnCreate method

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
```

It sets the "internal" workings of the app to English and all my input is in English.
But the best part is that it maintains and adopts the user's locale for the strings and what not.